# Facebook Graph or not to Graph for Profile Pic

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to create a simple Facebook app that pulls the logged in users Facebook profile photo within the app. Would I need to hook up an entire "connect to facebook" application or can it be done simply within the Facebook app without any permissions?

Thanks in advance, 
Hope all is well ...

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy.

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{userId}/picture" />
```

You can also add type attribute, like

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{userId}/picture?type=large" />
```

Supported types: small, normal, large, square

Comment: Thanks @vahe-hovhannisyan, but are you able to get the Facebook userId without asking permissions at any point? As in, they simply visit the Facebook app, "oh hey there userName with userId, what's haps?" ... Or do I need to connect them? Know what I mean?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken in that case you have to initialize facebook app, then use http://graph.facebook.com/me/picture.

Comment: No, you will have to have the user connect to your app first – otherwise there are no means for you to know their id. (Would be horrible from a privacy perspective, if any sites could read my FB id if I was only browsing them.) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/